# Fields not editable if they placed on an Form loaded into an iframe using dojox.mobile and the inapp browser of a cordova app

Tags: cordova, xpages, dojox.mobile

I know, this is really a special problem, but I need help!

We have built a single page application using dojox.mobile (xpages hosted on a domino server) and a cordova app (ios and android) to provide an easy way to access and use the single page application. Now I got some error reports of our ios users regardings the behavior of editing the fields. The users can enter and edit any field, but if they try to place the cursor at an other position or if the leave and enter a field again (by touching into the form and then into the field again), the cursor is shown and the keyboard is displayed, but they can enter any text. The only thing that works is to remove letters.

After some tests, I identified, that the problem only can be reproduced in the inapp browser, if dojox.mobile is loaded and the form is placed into an iframe. If I use safari (ios) or chrome (android), everything works fine. Unfortunately I need both, the iframe and dojox.mobile.

I have used the latest versions of the inapp browser plugin and dojo, but the problem is still reproduceable.

Is there any possibility to fix this issue?

Thanks!
Best regards,
Benjamin

Comment: Yesterday I have built a new simple cordova app with the current inapp browser plugin and a new simple single page app without using xpages or a domino server. The issue can be reproduced with the latest versions of dojo and the inapp browser plugin.

Answer (score 0):

You most likely need to redesign your solution. The combination of technologies chosen is sufficiently rare.

- The "perfect" solution would be an offline-first application (React Native, Ionic) that talks to you backend using JSON (using XPages Rest controls).
- The pragmatic version: Ditch the cordova part for ios. You can add a desktop icon on iOS which will launch the app in proper Safari.
- This lib might help: https://code.google.com/archive/p/mobile-bookmark-bubble/ to automate that (to some extend)

Hope that helps

Comment: Hi stwissel, thanks for the answer. I thought about the redesign of the solution in the past, but the problem is the effort of this redesign. The current xpage solution was build with an  investment of some man years.
I hope anybody knows the inner logic of dojox.mobile to identify the reasons and can create a fix.

Comment: The pragmatic solution isn't useable regarding two reasons. First, we are currently enhance our solution with "offline" views and forms (using Ionic). This will be your "perfect" solution in a far future. The second reason is that there are problems with dojo if i use a desktop bookmark! I don't understand that the behavior is diffrent if I use a desktop bookmark or open the "app" directly in safari, but it is reproduceable!

Comment: Dojox.mobile is technical debt you need to resolve. You are already using Ionic, so bite the bullet and go full Ionic. You probably can reuse most of the server side.